# json data parsing with jquery and HTML

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing

i am trying to parse json data from remote URL using Jquery. My data is in below format:

```
[
{
    "UserId": "5",
    "Name": "Syed",
    "Lat": "23.193458922305805",
    "Long": "77.43331186580654",
    "EmailId": "syedrizwan@ats.in",
    "LocationUpdatedAt": ""
},
{
    "UserId": "98",
    "Name": "Michael Catholic",
    "Lat": "23.221318",
    "Long": "77.42625",
    "EmailId": "michaelcatholic@gmail.com",
    "LocationUpdatedAt": ""
}
]
```

i have checked the data in json lint and it says it is correct data format. when i try to run it on my HTML page , it returns a blank page. My HTML code is a below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Jquery Json</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/fbJson/json.php', function(results){
        document.write(results.Name);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to retrieve names from the json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` is an array of items, so you have to consider which item you want.

Normally, you'd go over the array in a loop, in a fashion similar to that:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/fbJson/json.php', function(results){
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log(results[i].Name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an array of objects, you can reach them directly by using the index

```
   $.getJSON('http://localhost/fbJson/json.php', function(results){
        document.write(results[0].Name);
    });
```

If you wish to iterate over the array you can use `$.each` and pass the `results` into it

```
   $.each(results, function(key, val) {
       document.write(val.Name);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is correct.
Use this code to access name in first row array:

```
document.write(results[0].Name);
```